# How to reduce temperature of 7805 voltage regulator?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, motor-controller

I have the built the circuit shown in the following block diagram.

[image: Block Diagram]

The issue I have is that the 7805 is getting much hotter than I anticipated - too hot to touch.  I have shown the relevant required currents in the diagram - these are approximate but very much the correct order of magnitude I believe for the purposes of this question.  The current required per LED is 20 mA and the currents shown for the motors are approximately those measured at full-speed/stalled.

Absolute maximum ratings for these chips per datasheets are:

LM293DNE
Vcc1 pin: 60 mA
Vcc2 pin: 24 mA

PIC16F1823:
VDD pin: 150mA

I am wondering whether it would be better were I to recalculate the values of R3 and R4 such that they may be connected directly to the battery output rather than the 7805 output.  My thinking is that I would have approximately 140 mA less current sourced by the 7805 which, with an input/output voltage differential over the device of 4V, amounts to 560 mW less power for the 7805 to dissipate as heat.  Is this correct?

If so ...

The 7805 datasheet is provided: [7805 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf?ts=1706872433998&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.pl%252F)

Where do I look to obtain the expected reduction in temperature of the 7805 by reducing the current through the device?  One of the charts on pp.9 relating to \$\theta_{JA}\$?  The 7805 I am using is in package TO-220 and is currently installed without any heatsink.

Comment: Why not hook the LED strings up to the 9V rail, and PWM the GPIO's at 55% duty cycle?

Comment: That data sheet covers four different packages.  Please _edit your question_ to tell us the total current draw (LEDs plus all chips), plus what package you're using, and/or give the complete part number including the trailing alpha-numeric characters that specify the package.  While you're at it, please include a photo, datasheet, and/or a part number for the heat sink you're using, or if you're using a surface-mount part, show us the layout of the thermal pads and any thermal layers.

Comment: @TimWescott - question has been edited to reflect the package/heatsink (good point, bad omission).  I could go through the other devices and figure out the current draw, but is that necessary for the purposes of this question in which I am asking just about the change which might result by connecting the LEDs to the 9V supply rather than the 7805 output?

Comment: Basically your options are to reduce the current, reduce the input voltage or add heatsinks. I'd start by taking the LEDs off the regulator, but a heatsink is probably a good idea too given the motor current.

Comment: @TimWescott  I've added the absolute maximum current ratings for the two chips per their datasheets

Comment: A common 9 volt battery won't last long at the currents you are suggesting.  You could ease the load on the battery a bit by connecting two or three LEDs in series with a suitable resistor, and connecting the LED groups directly to the battery.

Comment: @PeterBennett - I like the series idea, but ... they have a forward voltage of approx 3.5V each.  I assume therefore that the compromise that would be faced is that once the battery falls to 8V there will be only half the current flowing through the LEDs that would be flowing at 9V?

Comment: "is currently installed without any heatsink."  Use a heatsink.  Even a small one makes a large difference.

Comment: Yes, the current will vary with battery voltage - but you need something to control the current.  Using two LEDs in series will reduce the load on the battery compared to having all the LEDs in parallel.  With the LEDs in parallel, you should have one resistor per LED, rather than a single resistor for five parallel LEDS.

Comment: Drawing current ~300mA with a voltage drop of 4V can make it really hot. Why not replace the 7805 with off-the-shelf DC-to-DC buck converter module like MP1482 or MP1584?

Comment: Yes, connecting the LEDs directly to the 9V through larger resistors is a good idea. The battery still has to supply the same total current but the 7805 is relieved of the LED current. That the LEDs will dim as battery fades is the least of your concerns - it won't take much fading before the 7805 will fall out of regulation anyway.

Comment: ...of course, the heat that the 7805 had been dissipating will now be dissipated in the larger resistors, so make sure they have an appropriate power rating.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you can improve the heat sinking in a number of ways including using a different package size of this LDO that has an exposed pad (or larger exposed pad) or by using a package size that can attach to a heat sink, such as a TO-220.  A fan is also an option to further remove heat.  If the LDO is getting that hot, clearly the load is too high for the present heat sinking.  You can move some of the loads to the battery, but note the battery is an unregulated voltage source so when the battery voltage starts to drop as the battery is discharged, it could affect things (like LED brightness).

Ideally, if you're using lots of current and you need everything to be on a consistent voltage, it's better to switch to a switching regulator instead of an LDO.  An LDO is basically a variable resistor and burns large amounts of heat in high current applications.  Switching regulators are much more efficient and don't produce as much heat in high current applications.  LDOs are nice in that they produce cleaner power than switching regulators, so if you want the best of both worlds (in applications that need clean supplies), you can use a switching regulator to get you most of the way to the voltage that you need, and an LDO to get you the rest of the way there.  The larger the voltage that an LDO has to drop, the more heat is generated, so by minimizing the required voltage that an LDO has to drop, you minimize the heat it creates.

So let's assume the output of your LDO shown above is 3.3V.  You can use a 9V to 3.3V switching regulator to feed everything that your LDO is presently feeding.  Or if you need clean power, you can use a switching regulator to get you down to 5V, and then use a 5V to 3.3V LDO to get you clean power.  It's a lot easier for an LDO to drop from 5V to 3.3V than it is for it to drop from 9V to 3.3V.

Comment: Please stop saying LDO.

Answer (score 1):

MPU:         150mAx (9V-5V) = 600mW (max)
Motor driver:(60mA+24mA)x (9V-5V) = 336mW (max)
LED1: (100mA)x (9V-5V) = 400mW (max)
LED2: (40mA)x (9V-5V) = 160mW (max)

So that is roughly 1.5W of heat you'll need to dissipate heat assuming that those currents are max currents. However you may want to measure average currents and/or calculate those, because odds are that none of the devices draw that much and you might be somewhere from 0.5-1W on average.

Another thing to do is find a 7805 that can handle the 1.5W and roughly 500mA max of current. at 1.5W If you wanted to keep the ambient temperature rise to 50C (above ambient) you would need to find a package with at least: 50C/1.5W = 33C/W. So it looks like many of the larger packages will work.

[image]
Source: [ST L78XX](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf)

But that is still a lot for most 7805's to handle. [Derate the 7805](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/290897/can-i-use-two-7805-ics-in-parallel-to-get-double-current-capacity) with external transistors (share the heat!) or get a DC DC.

If cost isn't an issue switch to a drop in [7805 DC DC converter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/132?s=N4IgTCBcDaIOwA4AMBWEBdAvkA)
They are easy to use and save a lot of power/heat.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't quite clear from the diagram

Comment: just to check I understand the ratings you have provided correctly.... If a rating (TO-220) is 50 C/W and the ambient temperature is 20C, then under ideal conditions a current of 1W passing through the 7805 should result in the junction being at 70C and the case at 65C.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of switching regulator modules which are drop in replacements for the classic 78xx linear regulators.  Sometimes the greater noise can cause issues, but in your case it seems a perfect match.

Chinese no-name units start at $1/unit and generally work well, but you can get quality units from suppliers such as [Murata](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807028260894/dms-78xxsr.pdf?1583754811000) for about $/unit.

[image]

(Image from Murata datasheet.)

Answer (score 1):

> How to reduce temperature of 7805 voltage regulator?

How to reduce the temperature of any linear regulator: by heat sinking it.

There is some simplicity to be gained from just "throwing a 7805 at the problem", so before you consider switching supplies and extensive circuit modifications, you'll find a heat sink to be the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution.

> the 7805 is getting much hotter than I anticipated - too hot to touch.

I have found retro computing experience (from the times when it was not retro, but state of the art), to be a good instructional tool :) Everything that used linear regulators ran scorching hot unless it was really over-designed, with lots of aluminum extrusions thrown at it, and cost accordingly. A 7805 running from a bit higher voltage than 9V will be tepid to touch just dissipating idle current + the minimum load current :)

> The 7805 I am using is in package TO-220 and is currently installed without any heatsink.

That's the problem, then. The heft of the heatsink will be inversely proportional to temperature reduction of the 7805. It's that simple, usually :)

> I am wondering whether it would be better were I to recalculate the values of R3 and R4 such that they may be connected directly to the battery output rather than the 7805 output.

To rephrase: you want to move all that heat from a relatively large voltage regulator that can (and should be!!) easily heatsunk, to presumably much smaller resistors that will get even hotter than the 7805 would be while dissipating the same power. Those resistors, presumably, are closer to the PCB than the body of the free-standing 7805, so the PCB won't be happy about that treatment either...

When designing for linear regulators, assume they have to be on a heatsink until thermal calculations or testing at the high end of the ambient temperature rating for your device shows otherwise.

For low volume or one-off devices, just throw an oversized heatsink there and you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can connect the LED directly to the 9V line. Either with 3 LED's in series, but as you said, they will glow dimmer and dimmer as the battery loses its power. Or with 2 LED's in series + a resistor or a linear current regulator in series with the LED's.

But the problem is not with the LED's. The problem is with the current used by the PIC16 and the motor driver. This current is proportional to the frequencies on the I/O and PWM pins. Higher frequencies on the PIC16 I/O pins will also result in more consumption in the motor driver. You should adapt your application in order to reduce these frequencies.

If there is no high frequencies, then there is a material defect in the circuit.

If there is no way to reduce the current consumption because the current consumption is normal and unavoidable, then you should replace the L7805 with a step down buck regulator. (It's possible that there are TO220 pin to pin compatible.) Because almost half of the power drawn by the circuit will be wasted by the L7805 (vs 5% to 15% with a step down regulator).

If the purpose is only to turn the LED's on and off, you will also save power by using transistor MOSFET's.

Comment: "vs. 15% with a step-down regulator" -- 85% at maximum load is a pretty poor efficiency for a step-down regulator these days.  As an example, [this part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-inc/P7805-Q24-S5-S/4009632) which I more or less randomly selected from the DigiKey site is 94% efficient.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, 85% is in the worst case.